# PySimpleGUI: How to make two elements on the same row with different expand?

Tags: pysimplegui

For less than six months I have been studying Python and now I am trying to write a graphical interface along with a library PySimpleGUI for one of my small programs, but I ran into a problem - I cannot arrange two elements with different expand on same row.

I find topic on github https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/issues/4566, in which this problem is voiced, but there were no specific solutions (as I understood, given my knowledge of English, corrections should have been made to the library with a new update).Here is part of my code

```
defect_col = [[sg.Tree(treedata, headings=[], key='-TREE1-',  expand_x=False), 
               sg.Table(values=ls_files,headings=header_list, key='-TABLE1-',expand_x=True)]]
window = sg.Window('SimpleWindow', defect_col , finalize=True, resizable=True)
window['-TREE1-'].expand(False, True)
window['-TABLE1-'].expand(True, True)
```

Help me, please with this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now the options `expand_x` and `expand_y`, and method `expand` of elements may not work well when elements with different option in a same row. To correct it, you may need the knowledge about method `pack` of widget.

Demo code as following,

```py
from random import choice
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def repack(widget, fill, expand, before=None):
    pack_info = widget.pack_info()
    pack_info.update({'fill':fill, 'expand':expand, 'before':before})
    print(pack_info)
    widget.pack(**pack_info)

treedata = sg.TreeData()
for i in range(20):
    parent = choice(list(treedata.tree_dict.keys()))
    treedata.insert(parent, i, f'Node {i:0>2d}', values=[f'Data {i:0>2d}'])

data = [[f"Cell ({row+1:0>2d}, {col+1:0>2d})" for col in range(2)] for row in range(50)]

font = ("Courier New", 11)
sg.theme("DarkBlue3")
sg.set_options(font=font)

layout = [
    [sg.Tree(data=treedata, headings=['COLUMN 1',], auto_size_columns=False,
        num_rows=10, col0_width=30, col_widths=[10], justification='center',
        show_expanded=True, enable_events=True, row_height=20, key='-TREE-',
        expand_x=False, expand_y=True),
     sg.Table(values=data, headings=['COLUMN 1', 'COLUMN 2'], auto_size_columns=False,
        col_widths=(20, 20), num_rows=10, justification='center', enable_events=True,
        alternating_row_color='green', select_mode=sg.TABLE_SELECT_MODE_EXTENDED,
        row_height=20, key='-TABLE-', expand_x=True, expand_y=True)],
]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout, size=(1200, 600), finalize=True)
tree, table = window['-TREE-'].Widget, window['-TABLE-'].Widget

repack(tree,        'y', 0)
repack(tree.master, 'y', 0, table.master)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
        break

    print(event, values)

window.close()
```

It show different options for a Tree and a Table at the same row.

- Tree with option `expand_x=False` and `expand_y=True` mean the element will automatically expand only in the Y direction to fill available space.
- Tree with option `expand_x=True` and `expand_y=True` mean the element will automatically expand in both of the X and Y direction to fill available space.

Actually, it is configured as (You can think `master` as the container)

```py
tree
<tkinter.ttk.Treeview object .!toplevel.!frame.!frame.!treeview>
side='left', fill='y', expand=1     # expand in y direction and get extra space in x direction

tree.master
<tkinter.Frame object        .!toplevel.!frame.!frame>
side='left', fill='y',    expand=1  # expand in y direction and get extra space in x direction

table
<tkinter.ttk.Treeview object .!toplevel.!frame.!frame2.!treeview>
side='left', fill='both', expand=1  # expand in both of x and y direction

table.master
<tkinter.Frame object        .!toplevel.!frame.!frame2>
side='left', fill='both', expand=1  # expand in both of x and y direction

tree.master.master or table.master.master
<tkinter.Frame object .!toplevel.!frame>
side='top', fill='both',  expand=1  # expand in both of x and y direction
```

You can find the pack settings for `tree` and `tree.master` are wrong, should be to expand only in y-direction. So we have give code to correct them after window finalized. The position of element maybe changed after unpack and repack, so we give the option `before=table.master` to repack it to correct position.

```py
repack(tree,        'y', 0)
repack(tree.master, 'y', 0, table.master)
```

Comment: You are gorgeous! Your solution to the problem is perfect, I tested it on several elements (tabs, table) and everything works as it should everywhere! Thanks a lot! For you, I should have learned English!

Comment: @iTech So vote his answer up and check the question as answered.